# deploying cloud functions with service account key is giving error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, github-actions, firebase-tools

Getting error:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/f6f117ed-3057-4628-abea-143e8aea4caf.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

when trying to deploy firebase functions via github

```
- name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
  uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
  with:
    credentials: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}

- name: Deploy functions
  run: npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions -P my-app-7d12z"
  env:
    FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
```

It works fine, if I remove `google-github-actions/auth` and go with --token approach instead of service account key

```
- name: Deploy functions
      run: npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions -P my-app-7d12z --token "$FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
      env:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
```

but then complaints that `--token approach is deprecated and will be removed in next version of firebase-tools`

Comment: Can you check with the permissions of the Service Account? As per this [Github Link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5340) by default the Service Account has 0 permissions. You can confirm the permissions issue by running the command with --debug and checking that output. And make sure you have this roles as stated in this [blog](https://davelms.medium.com/deploy-firebase-functions-using-github-actions-7dbafbd4df77).